# bpython get all possible completions

Tags: python, code-completion, bpython

For example, when I type

```
from some.module import a
```

I get list of what begins with "a"

How can I get the whole list, not for only "a" or other letter?

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible but if you'd post it on our bugtracker: http://bitbucket.org/bobf/bpython/issues

Maybe there is a way with a timer in our new frontend to show all possibilities.